# Verify multiple invocations with different parameters of some method using moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have some repository and I have a method which I would like to test which is invoked in the loop with parameter as an array. This method is taking values from array by 100 items at a time. So if I have an array with 434 items method should be invoked 5 times.

So how exactly can I test this method if e.g. I need to verify this method to be invoked 5 times with passing as a parameter array with 434 items?

```
var items = GetListOfStrings(434); // return list with 434 items

context.Mock<ISomeRepository>()
            .Verify(method => method.GetSomeItems(It.IsAny<string[]>(), Times.Exactly(5)));
```

Right now I'm passing as a parameter `It.IsAny<string>()`, but I would like to pass `items` and take next 100 items per one method invocation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may pass ranges of `items` and verify calls by comparing if two arrays contains the same elements (using `SequenceEqual`):

```
List<string> items = GetListOfStrings(494);

Mock.Get(someRepository).Verify(repository => repository.GetSomeItems(It.Is<string[]>(strings => strings.SequenceEqual(items.GetRange(0, 100)))), Times.Once);
Mock.Get(someRepository).Verify(repository => repository.GetSomeItems(It.Is<string[]>(strings => strings.SequenceEqual(items.GetRange(100, 100)))), Times.Once);
Mock.Get(someRepository).Verify(repository => repository.GetSomeItems(It.Is<string[]>(strings => strings.SequenceEqual(items.GetRange(200, 100)))), Times.Once);
// ...
```

Comment: @MaximKonyuh. You're welcome, I'm glad I could help.